# Creating list of photos in Django

Tags: django, django-models

On the webpage I am currently working on I have to display profiles of different persons. Each person has a profile image that is displayed on the right side. Furthermore, I have the content saved as markdown on the server.

Now I want to add the possibility to add an optional list of images that are displayed under the text and shows something about the person. My model for the person looks like that:

```
class stipendiat(models.Model):
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name   = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content     = models.TextField()
    year        = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    form        = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to='stipendiaten/', blank=True, null=True, default='default.jpg')
    gallery     = # This is the question

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
```

Because I want to save some data about the image the model should look like that:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    caption     = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    year        = models.IntegerField()
    image       = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path_handler, blank=False, null=False)
```

For convenience it should be possible to add an image while editing the form for the person. To be precise, I want to add a person and fill in the necessary information (first_name, last_name, content etc.). At the end should be a list of connected images and a button to add an image rapidly.

Is it necessary to use an external app or is there an elegant solution with relation fields?

Comment: The best solutions seems to be to add an ForeignKey to the GalleryImage model and use an inline admin to add them very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use a different model for the gallery images and a foreign key field to link the two models together

```
class Image(models.Model):
    #...
    stipendiat = models.ForeignKey(Reporter)
```

Now you can retrieve the Gallery Images for a stipendiat with id 1 like this

```
Image.objects.filter(stipentiat__pk=1)
```

Comment: Thank you. But why should I subclass my existing Image class?

Comment: So you can distinguish between the images in your gallery and the profile image.

Comment: But I save the profile image in the user model because I do not need a caption for that. My problem is that I need a way to create an image while filling I the form for the user. This is typical for a ManyToMany relation

Comment: Yes, sorry. You don't have to subclass Image, that's right.
But you cannot use the stipendiat in any relationship if it is not persisted, so you could either persist an 'empty' stipendiat and then add the photos.
Or you don't allow adding photos before the stipendiat was saved.
Or you persist them right when you persist the stipendiat